# Event to change to Nomad CK2

Tags: crusader-kings-2

In the recent Horse Lords DLC, there is a government system called the nomads.

Is there any way to trigger, or any event ID, to change to this type of government?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but:

1. You can try moving your capital to a nomadic county(after conquering it)
2. Somehow send your heir to nomads, and make him a nomad(so that when he inherits from you, you will be a nomad as well)